# Why does Golang http request with tls certificate gives handshake failure?

Tags: go, ssl, tls1.2, handshake

This is my code to add certificate to the request:

```
cer, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("certificate.pem", "mydomain.key")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    client.SetTLSClientConfig(&tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify:       true,
        PreferServerCipherSuites: true,
        Certificates:             []tls.Certificate{cer},
        MinVersion:               tls.VersionTLS12,
        MaxVersion:               tls.VersionTLS12,
    })
```

pem and key file is extracted from a jks file, using jks inside Burp Suite, the requests reach server perfectly, but when trying it with golang it says: `remote error: tls: handshake failure`

Comment: It is normal, ignore it. When I test my service via postman occasionally it spits this error. But in production I don't have them.

Comment: @tau I can't ignore it because I don't get any response from server.